# How to write logs for certain tasks only?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using Ansible and created a Playbook for deployment. I defined `log_path` in `ansible.cfg` and now tasks output are going to this log file. I want to send only few task's log into this log file. How can I achieve this ?

One option is to use `no_log: True` attribute but this is not displaying the logs on console.

So my requirement is to display all task's logs in console but I want to send only few task's log to my log file.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the wish list, I think. Quoting from the doc [log_plays - write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/log_plays.html)

```
* This callback writes playbook output to a file per host in the /var/log/ansible/hosts directory
* TODO: make this configurable
```

IMHO required functionality is not available at the moment. Take a look at the available plugins. "[You can only have one plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback.html#managing-stdout)".

```
ansible-doc -t callback -l
```

There is an option to customize a callback. [context_demo](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/context_demo.html) looks promising.

Comment: I got this info but there is not much documentation in link. Right now logs are going in the file but I want to stop that log for certain tasks (not hosts) and problem  that I can't use no_log: True because I want to print them on console.